# Instagram Authentication Page Doesn't Auto Redirect When The User Is Logged In on Another Tab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, authentication, instagram-api

I did my best to find a similar problem, but I did not come across one. I speculate this error may have been introduced with Instagram recently changing its API. I'm wondering if anyone else came across the same issue.

I use instagram for authentication. The problem is that, when a user is logged in to Instagram on another tab, if he clicks the instagram sign-in button to log in to my app, he lands on the [instagram authorization page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQMZo.png) and is asked to enter username and password. The problem is that instagram is supposed to auto-redirect to my app directly since the user is already logged in on the browser. But this doesn't happen. Moreover, even if the user enters wrong password or empty user name, instagram still redirects to my app with the logged in user. So the browser definitely knows that the user is logged in to instagram. I am quite sure that the problem is related to instagram, because when I change the provider settings to twitter, redirection occurs with no problem.

And this problem occurs for returning users as well.

For reference, I use rails 4 and my authentication strategy is omnioauth-instagram (no devise). I mainly followed this tutorial http://www.sitepoint.com/rails-authentication-oauth-2-0-omniauth/ for authentication. I am still in development mode so I use localhost.

**EDIT:** Here is the instagram notice:Instagram Platform and documentation update. Apps created on or after Nov 17, 2015 will start in Sandbox Mode and function on newly updated API rate-limits and behaviors. Prior to going Live, and being able to be used by people other than the developers of the app, these apps will have to go through a new review process. Please read the API documentation or the Change Log for more details.

I started creating my app before nov 17th.

Comment: This started happening recently few days ago, I noticed this issue also on http://gramfeed.com, I'll find out from Instagram.

Comment: Thanks! The funny thing is I couldn't even report this to instagram, because when I click on 'support', it asks me to log in (even though I am logged in), and when I log in, it takes me to the landing page for developers again..